# Android Studio Variable Button Name

Tags: android

I try to learn myself some android, I have a very basic question, that google wasn't able to answer me yet.

I want to improve my skills by trying to make a little XOX game. The first step of the "AI" is meant to be random.

```
if (Zugzahl == 1) {
    while (var == 0) {
        Random();

        if (ACButton[Rand].getText().equals = "X") {
            Random();
        } else {
            ACbutton[Rand].setText() = "O";
            var = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

`Random()` is a little line, that rules out the 0 as a number. I basically want the Random number added to my ACButton name, to address it right.

Thank you for your help

Here is the whole thing:

```
 package com.example.abu.myapplication;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button ACButton1;
private Button ACButton2;
private Button ACButton3;
private Button ACButton4;
private Button ACButton5;
private Button ACButton6;
private Button ACButton7;
private Button ACButton8;
private Button ACButton9;
private int Zugzahl;
private int Rand;
private double var;
private String[] ACButton = {String.valueOf(ACButton1), String.valueOf(ACButton2), String.valueOf(ACButton3), String.valueOf(ACButton4), String.valueOf(ACButton5), String.valueOf(ACButton6), String.valueOf(ACButton7), String.valueOf(ACButton8), String.valueOf(ACButton9)};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ACButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ACButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!ACButton1.getText().equals("0")) {
                ACButton1.setText("X");
                Zugzahl = Zugzahl + 1;
                Logic();

            }
        }
    });
    ACButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    ACButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!ACButton2.getText().equals("O")) {
                ACButton2.setText("X");
                Zugzahl = Zugzahl + 1;
                Logic();
            }
        }
    });
    ACButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    ACButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!ACButton3.getText().equals("O")) {
                ACButton3.setText("X");
                Zugzahl = Zugzahl + 1;
                Logic();
            }
        }
    });
    ACButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    ACButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!ACButton4.getText().equals("O")) {
                ACButton4.setText("X");
                Zugzahl = Zugzahl + 1;
                Logic();
            }
        }
    });
    ACButton5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    ACButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!ACButton5.getText().equals("O")) {
                ACButton5.setText("X");
                Zugzahl = Zugzahl + 1;
                Logic();
            }
        }
    });
    ACButton6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    ACButton6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!ACButton6.getText().equals("O")) {
                ACButton6.setText("X");
                Zugzahl = Zugzahl + 1;
                Logic();
            }
        }
    });
    ACButton7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    ACButton7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!ACButton7.getText().equals("O")) {
                ACButton7.setText("X");
                Zugzahl = Zugzahl + 1;
                Logic();
            }
        }
    });
    ACButton8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    ACButton8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!ACButton8.getText().equals("O")) {
                ACButton8.setText("X");
                Zugzahl = Zugzahl + 1;
                Logic();
            }
        }
    });
    ACButton9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    ACButton9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!ACButton9.getText().equals("O")) {
                ACButton9.setText("X");
                Zugzahl = Zugzahl + 1;
                Logic();
            }
        }
    });
}


private void Logic() {


    while (!ACButton1.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton4.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton7.getText().equals("X") ||
            !ACButton2.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton5.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton8.getText().equals("X") ||
            !ACButton3.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton6.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton9.getText().equals("X") ||
            !ACButton1.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton2.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton3.getText().equals("X") ||
            !ACButton4.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton5.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton6.getText().equals("X") ||
            !ACButton7.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton8.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton9.getText().equals("X") ||
            !ACButton1.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton5.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton9.getText().equals("X") ||
            !ACButton7.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton5.getText().equals("X") && !ACButton3.getText().equals("X")) {

        if (Zugzahl == 1) {
            while (var == 0) {
                Random();
                if (ACButton[Rand].getText().equals = "X") {
                    Random();
                } else {
                    ACButton[Rand].setText() = "O";
                    var = 1;
                }


            }


        }
    }
}


private void Random() {

    Rand = new Random().nextInt(9);

}

private void endgame() {
}
```

}

Comment: I think "XOX" is called "Tic Tac Toe" on English. AKA "Connect Three". 
But - what's your question about again?

Comment: It is also called Tic Tac toe in germany, but writing XOX is easier. I have the [Rand] in the code as the place where the variable number for my fields goes in. however i do not know how to bring Android studio to accept the Rand variable as the actual number from the field. My nine fields are called ACButton1 till 9. and i wanna switch out the fix number with a random one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your ACButton array with length of 9.
Each cell will contain his ACButton: For example 
`ACButton[0] = ACButton0`.

Use a random function, something like this:

```
Rand = new Random().nextInt(9); // random number in [0,8]
```

Later when you use: `if (ACButton[Rand].getText().equals = "X")`
You can achieve get your ACButton corresponding to his name according to his index in the array.

**Update:**
You get an exception because you create array of `String` with the value of the `ACButton`. Hence you can't get his text with `getText()`.
Try to create the array of the Buttons:

```
private Button[] ACButton = {ACButton1, ACButton2, ...};
```

This way you can get the `Button` instance and use his methods.

Comment: Okay, i made an array with all my Buttons in it. However the if (ACButton[Rand].getText().equals = "X") line does not work. The .getText and later on .setText method does not work.

Comment: Can you add your `ACButton` class code to your question?

Comment: I've uploaded the whole code. mabye makes things easier. Thanks for the support so Far.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Notice that your implementation can be improved.

Comment: @AlessandroBüch I wonder if it worked? can you give some feedback?

Comment: I had to use a different approach.   private Button[] ACButton = new Button[9]; made an array and filled it ACButton[0] = ACButton1; ACButton[1] = ACButton2; ACButton[2] = ACButton3; ACButton[3] = ACButton4;
                ACButton[4] = ACButton5; ACButton[5] = ACButton6; ACButton[6] = ACButton7; ACButton[7] = ACButton8;
                ACButton[8] = ACButton9; more or less like this. That works with the rest of my lines Thank you very much for your help, otherwise i wouldn't have figured that out....and thank google. ^^

Comment: You are welcome to mark my answer as solved, thank you.